# Node.js - Specifying URL in Heroku yields internal server error, running locally works fine

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm having some issues with my application after it's been deployed to heroku.  When I specify the URL, or refresh the browser on a page OTHER than the homepage I am getting an "Internal Server error" and the page doesn't load.  However when I click the links which naviagte me to those pages from the home page it works fine.  When I run the server locally it does not give me this error.

Based on my research this is probably an error on the server side.  Here is my code:

**Node.js backend**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const actions = require("./routes/api/dbActions");
const app = express();

// Bodyparser middleware
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/dbActions", actions);

// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port} !`));
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my server.js file I included the following:

```
const path = require('path');
```

Which seems to have worked for me.